# How to "unlink" a Perl array reference from the referenced variable?

Tags: perl, arrays, reference

In Perl 5.10.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @a = (1, 2, 3);
my $b = \@a;
print join('', @{$b}) . "\n";
@a = (6, 7, 8);
print join('', @{$b}) . "\n";
```

This prints 123 then 678.  However, I'd like to get 123 both times (i.e. reassigning the value of `@a` will not change the array that `$b` references).  How can I do this?

Comment: Obligatory warning:  **Do not** use variables named `$a` or `$b` in general Perl code.  `$a` and `$b` are globals used by the `sort` function and they will be overwritten if `sort` gets called by your code or by any module it uses.  (Yes, I realize that declaring them lexically (with `my`) sidesteps that because you're not using the global version then, but it's still asking for trouble to use `$a` or `$b`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a reference to a copy of `@a`.

```
my $b = [ @a ];
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Similarly, `my $b = { %a };` works with hashes.  I notice that no similar trick is needed for code references though - why is that?

Comment: I'm basically doing `my $a = sub { ... }; my $b = $a;`.  Then when I reassign `$a` to a different coderef, `$b` doesn't change (which is the behavior I want; I was just wondering why that happens).

Comment: Because $b isn't a reference to $a. When you do `$a = sub { ... }` later on, you're creating a new coderef and putting it in $a -- which doesn't replace the thing that $b points to. The difference here is that a coderef is always a ref -- you never work with non-ref "code values".

Comment: Note that if @a contains references, this will still have a reference to the original data in $b. For complex data structures you should use something like Storable's clone.

Answer (score 0):

Bretter use dclone for deep cloning of references pointing to anonymous data structures.